# Reverse a string in place - NASM x86 Assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm, machine-code

I am trying to write a code in NASM to reverse a string in place, but I keep getting seg fault. I have found a few asking similar questions, but the responses did not help me.

Heres the code:

```
    %include "asm_io.inc"

    segment .data

    prompt1         db      `Enter String: `,0
    prompt2         db      "Reverse: ",0

    segment .bss

    stringlabel     resd    100

    segment .text

    global reverse
    extern printf
    extern scanf

    reverse:

    call    readstring
    call    strlen
    mov     eax, 5
    mov     ebx, stringlabel        ;save first address of the string
                                    ;eax contains the string length
    add     eax, ebx                ;last address of the string
    sub     eax, 1                  ;account for null character

    whileReverse:

    mov     ecx, [eax]              ;save value of last marker into a temp register
    mov     edx, [ebx]              ;save value of first marker into a temp register
    mov     [ebx], ecx              ;save value in ecx to the memory location pointed by ecx
    mov     [eax], edx              ;save value in edx to the memory location pointed by eax
    inc     ebx                     ;increment first marker, i.e,move closer to the centre
    dec     eax                     ;decrement last marker
    cmp     eax, ebx                ;if first marker is larger then the second marker, then swapping is done
    ja      whileReverse

    whileReverseEnd:

    popa
    leave
    ret


    readstring:

    enter   0,0                     ;setup routine
    pusha                           ;push all registers
    mov     eax, prompt1            ;move user input (String) into the register
    call    print_string            ;print prompt  on terminal


    ;READ A BYTE FROM STDIN
    ;this sub-block of code is to read the user input
    ;I found it on the NASM wikibooks site
    ;I have an idea of what may be going on
    ;But I am not sure why all these registers
    ;are being used

    mov     eax, 3                  ;read
    mov     ebx, 0                  ;read from standard input
    mov     ecx, stringlabel        ;address to pass
    mov     edx, 100                ;input length
                                    ;must save the input string
                                    ;in eax (requirement)
    int     0x80                    ;call the kernal
    call    print_string            ;print user input on terminal
    popa
    ret

    strlen:

    enter   0,0
    pusha

    mov     eax, prompt1            ;save the address of the first memory 'block' of stringlabel in eax
    mov     ebx, eax                ;move both markers to the first memory 'block' address

    whileLen:

    mov     cl, [eax]               ;move value from eax to lower ecx
    cmp     cl, 0                   ;look for null value in the current address
    je      whileLenEnd             ;exit loop if null value is found in the current address
    inc     eax                     ;else, increment eax to move on to the next memory location or 'block'
    jmp     whileLen                ;jump back to while loop and repeat

    whileLenEnd:

    sb      eax, ebx                ;subtract the final positions of the markers to calculate the string length must save the string length in eax {requirement)
    pop     ebx
    pop     ecx
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: In the `strlen` routine you are pushing all registers at the beginning, but only popping `ebx` and `ecx` at the end.

Comment: `mov ecx, [eax]` moves four bytes, while your code seems to assume it moves one byte.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning 5 to EAX defeats the purpose of calling strlen. Just remove it.

```
call    strlen
mov     eax, 5
```

The comment on the following line is wrong. The decrement is needed to place EAX on the last character of the string.

```
sub     eax, 1                  ;account for null character
```

You need to treat characters as bytes in stead of dwords.

```
mov     cl, [eax]  ;save value of last marker into a temp register
mov     dl, [ebx]  ;save value of first marker into a temp register
mov     [ebx], cl  ;save value in ecx to the memory location pointed by ecx
mov     [eax], dl  ;save value in edx to the memory location pointed by eax
```

This code will NOT correctly exit the program. Call the kernal's EXIT function.

```
whileReverseEnd:

popa
leave
ret
```

Since *readstring* uses `enter 0,0` you need to add a matching `leave` between `popa` and `ret`.

In *strlen* it is easier to not use `pusha`. That way EAX can be returned!

```
strlen:
enter   0,0
push    ecx
push    ebx
mov     eax, prompt1  ; <-- Change this to    stringlabel
```

The next line has probably a typo. Change **sb** into `sub`.

```
sb      eax, ebx                ;subtract the final positions
```

Answer (score -1):

```
;***************************************************
;
; Reversing a string in 8086 ALP
;
; code by Akshay Rajput
;****************************************************

section .data
msg db "microprocessor"
len: equ $-msg

section .bss
rstring resb 14

section .code 
global _start

_start:
    %macro write 2
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,%1
    mov edx,%2
    int 80h
    %endmacro

    %macro read 2
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,%1
    mov edx,%2
    int 80h
    %endmacro

    mov esi,msg
    mov ecx,14
    add esi,len-1
    mov edi,rstring

AGAIN:mov eax,[esi]
    mov [edi],eax
    dec esi
    inc edi
    LOOP AGAIN

    write rstring,14



    mov eax,1
    int 80h
```

Comment: Why is your `loop` instruction in all-caps, when none of the other instructions are?  More importantly, why are you using [the slow `loop` instruction at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently)?  But anyway, you're making the same mistake as the OP: you're loading/storing 4 bytes, so you overwrite parts of the string you haven't read yet.  See Sep's answer which already answers this.

Comment: Also, 8086 doesn't have 32-bit registers.  This code needs at least a 80386 to run.  (Also for the 32-bit Linux system calls.)